# Is there a way that I can plot a graph given an entry's X value and its Y value as its height?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose that I have this data frame

[image]

I want to plot a graph of where `p` is on the horizontal axis and `prior` is on the vertical axis such that I have this:

[image]

Note: I know that one can use `geom_barplot()` but that would entail that I have multiple entries where `p` is `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3`, etc. But the picture of the data frame is the entire data frame with 9 rows from `0.1` to `0.9`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data in questions. See why this is not recommended [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5241032).

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is named `df`: `ggplot(df, aes(p, prior)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. `stat = "identity"` is key here. Read more [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/).

Comment: @cmaher understandable thanks!

Comment: `geom_col()` would also be equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`